# Windows 10 Limit bluetooth headset connection only when user logs in

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headset

my firm has thin clients on the flex work space with connection to VDI infrastructure use it citrix. I have paired my headset to the thin client after I log in to thin client. However next day even when someone else logs in to the thin client, my headset still connects to that. How can I make sure that bluetooth connections are on per user basis and not global.

Thanks,